# Not Getting Response while initiating Session on Net::SNMP while accessing the device with snmpv3 credentials using AES-256

Tags: perl, cpan, net-snmp

I am facing issue with accessing the device with snmpv3 users with AES-256 credentials.

```
  initiating the session with below arguments

  ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(%args);
```

When I am trying with AES-256 I am not able to access the device and I'm not getting any response also and already I have users in device with AES-256.

```
Not-Working Scenarios :-
$args = {
   auth_password => 'Airwave@123',
   auth_protocol => 'sha',
   ip => '10.21.42.250',
   localaddr => '10.2.34.205',
   nonblocking => 1,
   port => 161,
   priv_password => 'Airwave@123',
   priv_protocol => 'aes256',
   username => 'user5',
   version => 3,
   warn => undef
};

Working scenarios :-
$args = {
 auth_password => '************',
 auth_protocol => 'sha',
 ip => '10.21.42.250',
 localaddr => '10.2.34.205',
 oids => [
   '.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.116.1.1.3.0'
 ],
 port => 161,
 priv_password => 'Aruba@123',
 priv_protocol => 'aes',
 username => 'user4',
 version => 3,
 warn => undef
};
```

If I sent arguments with AES-128 I can able to access. I am not able to access only when I am trying with AES-256.

I have upgraded the CPAN module Net::SNMP and upgraded the net-snmp 5.9 module also which is have support AES-256.

Can any one please check and help me how to access the device with AES-256 through `Net::SNMP->session`.

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with SNMP, but maybe you could [enable debugging output](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP#debug()-set-or-get-the-debug-mode-for-the-module) to get more information about what is going on?